# How do I measure the statistical significance of a boolean value?

Tags: statistical-significance, error

Let's say I have a function `simulate()` that returns `True` with some probability $p$ and False otherwise.

After calling `simulate()` $N$ times, I get `True` $x$ times and `False` $N - x$ times. I then compute $p' = \frac{x}{N}$. How do I measure my error on $p'$? My ultimate goal is to figure out whether $p > 0.5$ for my `simulate()` function, and I want to know how many trials I have to conduct to be confident in my result.

Comment: Many answers to questions just like can be found at http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+proportion+sample+size.

Comment: How many trials depends on the true value of p. If p=1, you can be very confident that p>0,5 after a handful of trials, but if p=0.5000001 you might need some milions of trials before being confident that p>0,5.

Comment: Sounds like you are after a test of a binomial proportion or a binomial confidence interval. Search for answers to questions about them on this site.

Answer (score 1):

By virtue of the fact that $X$ has a binomial distribution, we know that the standard error for $p'$ is $p(1-p)/N$.  Now $p$ is the unknown variable we wish to estimate so we get an estimate by replacing $p$ with $p'$. If $N$ is large enough we can use a normal approximation for $p'$ and take $\pm 2$ estimated standard deviations around $p'$ as an approximate 95% confidence interval for $p'$. This would be a two-sided interval. Since you only want to know if $p>0.5$, you might prefer using a one-sided interval.

Answer (score 1):

Your data are independent binary variables with a fixed probability, so the count value you are seeking is a binomial random variable.  You already have a point estimate, so the next step is to use an appropriate interval estimator, such as a confidence interval.  This is a very well-known problem, so I recommend you start by reading some textbook presentations of binomial confidence intervals.  You can also read [Brown et al (2001)](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ss/1009213286) for an overview of available methods, and comparison between methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are working with a binomial distribution. Its variance for a sample of n observations with a "p" chance of getting a "true result" is n*p*(1-p)

Therefore its standard deviation will be the square root of n*p*(1-p) (use the results you got before to estimate p, ie: use the sample p as "kind-of-the-true-p") You can now calculate confidence intervals and all those cool things you can do with normal distributions (for a large enough sample, it will behaive similarly)